# "SchemaRegistryException: Failed to get Kafka cluster ID" for LOCAL setup

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I'm downloaded the .tz (I am on MAC) for confluent version `7.0.0` from the official confluent site and was following the setup for **LOCAL** (1 node) and **Kafka**/**ZooKeeper** are starting fine, but the **Schema Registry** keeps failing (Note, I am behind a corporate VPN)

[image]

The exception message in the SchemaRegistry logs is:

```
[2021-11-04 00:34:22,492] INFO Logging initialized @1403ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog (org.eclipse.jetty.util.log)
[2021-11-04 00:34:22,543] INFO Initial capacity 128, increased by 64, maximum capacity 2147483647. (io.confluent.rest.ApplicationServer)
[2021-11-04 00:34:22,614] INFO Adding listener: http://0.0.0.0:8081 (io.confluent.rest.ApplicationServer)
[2021-11-04 00:35:23,007] ERROR Error starting the schema registry (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication)
io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.exceptions.SchemaRegistryException: Failed to get Kafka cluster ID
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.kafkaClusterId(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:1488)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.<init>(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:166)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.initSchemaRegistry(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:71)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.configureBaseApplication(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:90)
    at io.confluent.rest.Application.configureHandler(Application.java:271)
    at io.confluent.rest.ApplicationServer.doStart(ApplicationServer.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain.main(SchemaRegistryMain.java:44)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(CompletableFuture.java:1784)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1928)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:180)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.kafkaClusterId(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:1486)
    ... 7 more
```

My `schema-registry.properties` file has bootstrap URL set to

```
kafkastore.bootstrap.servers=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
```

I saw some posts saying its the SchemaRegistry unable to connect to the KafkaCluster URL because of the localhost address potentially. I am fairly new to Kafka and basically just need this local setup to run a git repo that is utilizing some Topics/Kafka so my questions...

1. How can I fix this (I am behind a corporate VPN but I figured this shouldn't affect this)
2. Do I even need the SchemaRegistry?

Comment: There's not really enough information to answer this. No, you don't need a Schema Registry to actually use Kafka itself. Localhost works fine and your VPN wouldn't be involved for loopback connections. Have you tried using Docker quickstart guide instead? Are you using an M1 Mac because I don't know if Confluent supports that

Comment: @OneCricketeer Hey, no this is an intel Macbook pro 16. I haven't tried the Docker quick start, The corporate VPN usually causes more issues using Docker but Ill try that now thanks

Comment: I mostly use Docker myself on my Mac (haven't tried Confluent 7.0, though). My other suggestion would be to not use `confluent local` commands, and just run `kafka-server-start` and `schema-registry-start` in separate windows since these are what you'd use in a real setup anyway. More specifically, the error seems to say that Kafka died or has some other connection issue for clients on its own, which you'd see better if you started it with `kafka-server-start`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just going with the Docker local setup inside, and the only change I had to make to the docker compose YAML was to change the schema-registry port (I changed it to 8082 or 8084, don't remember exactly but just an unused port that is not being used by some other Confluent service listed in the docker-compose.yaml) and my local setup is working fine now

Comment: OK, this helped me - but I was also a dope and had my memory setting in docker set too low (default on OSX is 2GB) and services would start and then tip over later. In case another dope comes along later and reads this...add more memory, too.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved that issue on my Mac by doing the following:

```
cd <confluent-dir>/etc/schema-registry
vim schema-registry.properties
```

Then I edited the file changing the following:

```
...
# Use this setting to specify the bootstrap servers for your Kafka cluster and it
# will be used both for selecting the leader schema registry instance and for storing the data for
# registered schemas.
kafkastore.bootstrap.servers=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
...
```

I saved and quit:
:wq

Then the following commands:

```
cd ../kafka
vim server.properties
```

In that file I have uncommented and edited the following line:

```
...
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
...
```

I saved and quit:
:wq

That was it, it worked like a charm. Good luck!